# File tags prevent autocomplete of global tags

Tags: auto-complete-mode, tags

I amended `.emacs` as shown below. Then `M-x load-file ~/.emacs`. What I want to do in `test.org` is add `MEntal` tags to each of the two entries, for example `Read` and `Reminder`, respectively. Using the column view I type 'e' in the tags column of the first entry, then 'R'. I expect 'Read' to autocomplete, instead I get '[No match]'. Is there something wrong with the global tag hierarchy defined in `.emacs`?

`~/.emacs`:

```
(setq org-tag-alist '(
              (:startgrouptag)
                      ("ACTivities")
                      (:grouptags)
                      ("MEntal")
                      ("PHysical")
                      ("TRansact")
                      (:endgrouptag)
                      (:startgrouptag)
                      ("MEntal")
                      (:grouptags)
                      ("Read")
                      ("Write")
                      ("Reminder")
                      (:endgrouptag)
              )
      )
```

`test.org`:

```
#+TAGS: [ editor : emacs ]

* 2019
** 2019-12 December
*** 2019-12-01 Sunday
**** TODO [#C] [[http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html][Helm-intro]]                                                                  :emacs:
     - State "TODO"       from              [2019-12-01 Sun 17:31]
**** `C-u C-c C-q` to realign tags                                                                  :emacs:
   Entered on [2019-12-01 Sun 20:29]
```

[image]

Comment: I can reproduce this, in two ways: trying to edit the TAGS column in columns view, or using `C-q` without columns view. It works fine without the explicit #+TAGS entry (which is wrong by the way: the syntax is `#+TAGS: tag1 tag2 tag3 ....` with no square brackets and no colons AFAIK). At first sight, it looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @NickD the syntax of the in file tag specification is borrowed [from the manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Tag-hierarchy.html) If I remove the line, autocomplete still ignores the globally defined tags.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the syntax. After removing the line, did you save the file, kill the buffer and reopen the file?

Comment: No, sorry, I hadn't. Now that I did, autocomplete works.  If add at the beginning, `#+TAGS: tag1 tag2`, and reload, it does not work. In other words local tag specs interferes. But I should be able to mix global and local tags, though.

Comment: You might want to bring it up on the [Org mode mailing list](https://orgmode.org/community.html).

Comment: Thanks, I just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was suggested to me through the `org-mode` mailing list: replace ‘org-tag-persistent-alist’ instead of `org-tag-alist` in ~/.emacs. I tried it: autocomplete works for both the local and global tag lists.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop!